# One controller for different area views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have MVC5 app which has 2 areas: area1 and area2. 
Some views in those areas are using code from controller which is actually same for view in area1 and view in area2.
Now I have 2 controllers per each area, but as I mentioned, the code is very same.
How can I use one Controller per each view in the area 1 and 2 to avoid code duplicity and have simpler maintainability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Areas are just a layer, but they can still interact with each other and the application at large. If you need to share a controller, you can simply subclass it. Better yet, create an abstract controller outside of the areas and inherit each area's controller from that.

As far as views go, Razor has a very easy convention for handling overrides and fallbacks. It searches multiple directories, based on convention, for the required view and stops only when it finds a match.

For example, if you placed the view in `Views\Shared`, the last resort fallback, it can be used literally anywhere in your application, including each of your areas. The order of ops for view location is:

1. `Areas\[AreaName]\Views\[ControllerName]`
2. `Areas\[AreaName]\Views\Shared`
3. `Views\[ControllerName]`
4. `Views\Shared`

Razor will go down the list looking for the view in each location until it finds it.

Answer (score 1):

You keep the separate controllers as they serve their purposes in the MVC framework. However, you can **export much of the code in the controllers to  service classes** and each controller uses the services as needed -- Now you *avoid code duplicity and have simpler maintainability*.

**Controllers**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IFooService service;

    public HomeController()
    {
        this.service = new FooService(dbContext);
    }

    public ActionResult CalculateFoo(int id)
    {
        var foo = this.service.CalculateFoo(id);
        return View(foo);
    }
}

public class FooController : Controller
{
    private IFooService service;

    public FooController()
    {
        this.service = new FooService(dbContext);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var foo = this.service.CalculateFoo(id);
        return View(foo);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private DbContext db;

    public FooService(DbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public Foo CalculateFoo(int id)
    {
        var foo = this.db.Foo.First(f => f.id == id);
        // do stuff
        return foo;
    }
}
```